# Mysql search for rows without a white space in it

Tags: mysql

It is possibile to search for rows that does not contain a white space in it?

I have try this but return an error

```
SELECT *  FROM `users` WHERE `name` 
NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: It works to me. What's the error msg?

Comment: Query is perfectly ok. You should include the error message into the question.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql 8 and newer you can use REGEXP_LIKE for more complicated expression too.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[[:blank]]')
```

[REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like)